# Can't understand how to send post to Lingvo API

Tags: rest, api, http

Can't understand how should look the following request

POST api/v1/authenticate

from here: [Lingvo API](https://developers.lingvolive.com/en-us/Help/Api/POST-api-v1-authenticate)

> It's said:  "Responds to POST request containing "Authorization: Basic
>   {ApiKey}" header."

I've tryend 
POST https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/authenticate with header `["Authorization":"BasicZjkzN2E4YTctZmUxMS00YTkxLThjMjEtYzBiOGU3NTY1Y2ZmOjk2NTUxYmI2YjRhNjRkOWRhNmQ5NTJkMzVlOWM2YjBk"]`

also tried POST https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/authenticate
with body

```
{"Authorization": "BasicZjkzN2E4YTctZmUxMS00YTkxLThjMjEtYzBiOGU3NTY1Y2ZmOjk2NTUxYmI2YjRhNjRkOWRhNmQ5NTJkMzVlOWM2YjBk"}
```

And every time getting 401 ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It would seem to me that you're just missing a space. [The docs](https://developers.lingvolive.com/en-us/Help/Api/POST-api-v1-authenticate) read that you should supply a header with the value:

```
"Authorization: Basic ZjkzN2E4YTctZmUxMS00YTkxLThjMjEtYzBiOGU3NTY1Y2ZmOjk2NTUxYmI2YjRhNjRkOWRhNmQ5NTJkMzVlOWM2YjBk"`
```

Rather than `Authorization: BasicZjkzN2[...]` as you have in your question.

I'll post my cURL output here that I used to validate my hypothesis. You're likely using a test account if you're sharing the API key on stackoverflow, but it's worth saying anyway: **do not use the credentials you've shared here in production!**

```
$ curl -X POST 'https://developers.lingvolive.com/api/v1/authenticate' -H 'Authorization: Basic ZjkzN2E4YTctZmUxMS00YTkxLThjMjEtYzBiOGU3NTY1Y2ZmOjk2NTUxYmI2YjRhNjRkOWRhNmQ5NTJkMzVlOWM2YjBk' -H 'Content-length: 0' -vvv


*   Trying 40.74.55.233...
* Connected to developers.lingvolive.com (40.74.55.233) port 443 (#0)
* TLS 1.2 connection using TLS_ECDHE_RSA_WITH_AES_256_CBC_SHA384
* Server certificate: *.lingvolive.com
* Server certificate: Go Daddy Secure Certificate Authority - G2
* Server certificate: Go Daddy Root Certificate Authority - G2
> POST /api/v1/authenticate HTTP/1.1
> Host: developers.lingvolive.com
> User-Agent: curl/7.49.1
> Accept: */*
> Authorization: Basic ZjkzN2E4YTctZmUxMS00YTkxLThjMjEtYzBiOGU3NTY1Y2ZmOjk2NTUxYmI2YjRhNjRkOWRhNmQ5NTJkMzVlOWM2YjBk
> Content-length: 0
>
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Cache-Control: no-cache
< Pragma: no-cache
< Content-Type: application/json; charset=utf-8
< Expires: -1
< Server: Microsoft-IIS/8.5
< X-AspNet-Version: 4.0.30319
< X-Powered-By: ASP.NET
< Date: Mon, 14 Nov 2016 14:06:46 GMT
< Content-Length: 318
<
* Connection #0 to host developers.lingvolive.com left intact
"ZXlKaGJHY2lPaUpJVXpJMU5pSXNJblI1Y0NJNklrcFhWQ0o5LmV5SmxlSEFpT2pFME56a3lNVGc0TURZc0lrMXZaR1ZzSWpwN0lrTm9ZWEpoWTNSbGNuTlFaWEpFWVhraU9qVXdNREF3TENKVmMyVnlTV1FpT2pRMkxDSlZibWx4ZFdWSlpDSTZJbVk1TXpkaE9HRTNMV1psTVRFdE5HRTVNUzA0WXpJeExXTXdZamhsTnpVMk5XTm1aaUo5ZlEuaWRQOHRGZXpCYVlHSm45MHJlU3VPRmtWSE43cnROdXVram1BdzkzN3FQQQ=="%
```

By the way, it looks like explicitly defining an accurate `Content-length: n` header is required. In this case, there is no body, so a value of `0` does the trick.